# jQuery keyup = instead of ==

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function in Javascript using jQuery, and it works the way I want to. The thing is, I made a typo and used the assignment operator instead of == or ===. For some reason the assignment operator works, whereas checking for equality == does not. The function below works, but it seems like it shouldn't. The part I am referring to is event.type = 'keyup'.  Any ideas why?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box" id = "box1">
<input class = "ti"  id = "t1" type="text"  placeholder= "Enter to do" >
</div>

<script>
$( ".ti" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
$( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
if (event.type = 'keyup' && event.which == '13') {
    alert('here');
}
});</script>
```

Comment: Unless I'm wrong here, an assignment will pretty much always equal true.  If you're curious why equality doesn't work, then log the actual content of `event.type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `event.type = 'keyup'` returns `keyup` and a non-empty string is a truthy value in JavaScript.

Edit: I missed the `&&` operator and it's role in the expression, maybe because I had focused on truthy nature of non-empty strings in JavaScript which is still relevant to what happens. So this answer is not completely correct in your case. As Kay has posted an answer which is correct I won't update this answer.

Comment: It is parsed as `event.type = ('keyup' && (event.which == '13'))`, which can be simplified to `event.type = (event.which == '13')`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript the logical AND (`&&`) has a higher precedence than an assignment (`=`, `+=`, …), i.e. `a = b && c` gets parsed as `a = (b && c)`.

So the condition `event.type = 'keyup' && event.which == '13'` gets parsed as `event.type = ('keyup' && (event.which == '13'))`. A non-empty string is truthy in JavaScript, so this expression can be simplified to `event.type = (event.which == '13')`. Notice that the string "keyup" is gone from the expression. Now an assignment evaluates to the assigned value, i.e. `event.type` gets overwritten with true or false depending on the value of `event.which`, and this comparison decides whether or not if-condition is true.